# I'm having trouble getting my player to climb up the edge

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I am building a free climbing system for a 3d Game like in Genshin Impact but I can't get my player to climb  up the edge,

I used double raycast to detect if it's an edge or not, if there is an edge, the  animation is triggered and I used matchTarget  as shown here

```
private bool edgeDetect()
    {
        RaycastHit firstHit;
        Vector3 position = transform.position + detectionOffcet;


        if (Physics.Raycast(position, transform.forward, out firstHit, 2f))
        {

            if (Physics.Raycast(firstHit.point + (transform.forward * playerRadius) + (Vector3.up * 0.6f * playerHeight), Vector3.down, out var secondHit, playerHeight))
            {
                Targetposition = secondHit.point+edgeOffcet;
                 m_Animator.SetTrigger("edge");
                Vector3 climbEnd = secondHit.point;
                m_Animator.MatchTarget(climbEnd, Quaternion.LookRotation(-firstHit.normal), AvatarTarget.Body, new MatchTargetWeightMask(Vector3.one, 0), 0, 0.09f); 
              return true; 
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

but this is not working properly, the player always falls and does not reach the edge, he gets stuck , Also if the wall is diagonal the detection system will be wrong,
how how can I fix this

Comment: If the first `if` enters, can't you figure out a way to avoid having a second `if`? Maybe this can simplify your thoughts. The condition of the second `if` is quite long and these hardcoded values sometimes cannot be trusted.

Comment: As far as I know, if you want to climb, you just need to throw a horizontal ray (not necessarily going to the direction `transform.forward`). The correct direction might be something like the normalized `transform.forward` with 0 in its y. And while this ray hits the wall, you should be able to climb.

Comment: I know that the problem is because I am shooting a raycast down an I am suppose to be shooting it diagonal to the wall's direction I just don't know how. and the main problem for me is how to move to the edge

Comment: You don't **need** to use a raycast. Have you considered a SphereCast?

Comment: Can you explain to me how could I change that with SphereCast

Comment: SphereCast is just like a raycast but instead of a ray, it draws a sphere and if this sphere touches a collider it will tell you. You just need to cast a SphereCast and fill its parameters. Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html).